# Adding Groovy class to Spring project

Tags: spring, groovy

I'm trying to add a Groovy class to an existing Spring Java project. I have been following the instructions from two different sources [1] & [2], however, it doesn't seem to work for me.

This is my Groovy class:

```
package com.example.service;

class MessageService {

    String message
}
```

This is my bean definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"

    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.5.xsd"
>

    <lang:groovy id="messenger" script-source="classpath:com.example.service.MessageService.groovy">
        <lang:property name="message" value="This is a Groovy message" />
    </lang:groovy>

</beans>
```

I have added the dependencies as described in the articles to my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
  <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

And updated my plugins:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>${java.version}</source>
            <target>${java.version}</target>
            <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
            <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
            <!-- <verbose>false</verbose> -->
        </configuration>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.0-01</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.8-01</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

However, when I run `mvn test` I can see that the Groovy compiler kicks in and all code "seem" to compile correctly but when the tests are run it goes in a bit of what seems like a loop trying to start the tests several times without throwing a precise error.

Is there anything in my definitions not correct?

[1] http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.3/reference/dynamic-language.html
[2] http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy-Eclipse+compiler+plugin+for+Maven#Groovy-EclipsecompilerpluginforMaven-WhyanotherGroovycompilerforMavenWhataboutGMaven

Comment: You are using the Groovy compiler however are expecting the groovy sources to be still there. Either use the compiler to create a .class file and use that directly as a normal bean or let the script support in spring take care of the .groovy file. Currently you are mixing 2 approaches.

Comment: Ah. OK. You're saying I should just treat it like a Bean and don't use the `<lang:groovy>` definition, correct?

Comment: OK. This seems to work perfectly. I added a test written in Groovy as well. Not sure why the Spring tutorial is so complicated for something that's almost trivial.

Comment: Why complicated? There is no mention in the tutorial to add the compiler, it only mentions the script nothing more. Not sure where you  got that compiler stuff from.